# Flutter/Supabase stream filters - why the one field filter limit?

Tags: flutter, supabase-database

Using the "flutter_supabase" package, I've been trying to add a dynamic filtered stream to my Flutter app, and have found that an exception is thrown if more than filter is applied.

Why the one field limit?  Is there any way around this?

In my case, I want to apply two filter fields to the stream, and the exact fields are applied dynamically based on user selections.

Answer (score 1):

Supabase has advised that this is limit set by their real time streaming layer.
Work arounds to solve this:
a). Build logical views to represent the different filters
b). add a 'where' clause to the stream results and filter at the client end