# How can I use two filters from supabase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

I am trying to stream data from supabase in flutter.

I want to fetch data that post_id is postId and deleted_at is null, so I tried to fetch using following code.

But if I use more than one filter, an error occurs that only one can be used.

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:supabase/src/supabase_stream_builder.dart': Failed assertion: line 90 pos 7: '_streamFilter == null': Only one filter can be applied to `.stream()`)
```

```
final response = Supabase.instance.client
  .from('comments')
  .stream(primaryKey: ['comment_id'])
  .eq('post_id', postId)
  .eq('deleted_at', null)
  .order('created_at', ascending: false);
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Supabase stream filters - why the one field filter limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212838/flutter-supabase-stream-filters-why-the-one-field-filter-limit)

Comment: See also [this issue](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-flutter/issues/338) on GitHub